# Applying Gaussian noise to a list of values

Tags: python, gaussian, probability-distribution

For sample selection from a list, I wish to use a mathematical distribution where the total number of samples is fixed, St = 1000 and there are 5 buckets such that the initial distribution is uniform. samples = [200, 200, 200, 200, 200]
I wish to add random Gaussian noise with mean 0 and 20% of uniform class weight as standard deviation, but the total number of samples should still be 1000.

This is my current code block

```
signal = np.array([200, 200, 200, 200, 200])
print('total samples: ', sum(signal))
noise = np.random.normal(0,0.2,5)
print('noise generated: ',noise)
val = (signal*noise)
val = np.round(val,0)
val = val+signal
print(val)
print('samples after weighted distribution: ',sum(val))
```

[image]

I want to apply weights but still maintain the total number of samples as 1000. How do I go about this?

Comment: Why not generate the 1000 samples first, make the noise = np.random.normal(0,0.2,1000) and then proceed ?

Comment: But the initial condition is 1000 samples being uniformly distributed in 'n' buckets, I have chosen n=5 in this case.

Comment: You are not making sense of the problem if you keep your "samples" as the number 200 in each bucket.

Comment: The values are 200 only to begin with. After applying a Gaussian noise the only criteria is being consistent with the total number of samples.